# Handling UUID values in Arrow with Parquet files

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I'm new to Python and Pandas - please be gentle!

I'm using SqlAlchemy with pymssql to execute a SQL query against a SQL Server database and then convert the result set into a dataframe. I'm then attempting to write this dataframe as a Parquet file:

```
  engine = sal.create_engine(connectionString)

  conn = engine.connect()
  df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
  df.to_parquet(outputFile)
```

The data I'm retrieving in the SQL query includes a `uniqueidentifier` column (i.e. a UUID) named `rowguid`. Because of this, I'm getting the following error on the last line above:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert UUID('92c4279f-1207-48a3-8448-4636514eb7e2') with type UUID: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type", 'Conversion failed for column rowguid with type object')
```

**Is there any way I can force all UUIDs to strings at any point in the above chain of events?**

A few extra notes:

- The goal for this portion of code was to receive the SQL query text as a parameter and act as a generic SQL-to-Parquet function.
- I realise I can do something like `df['rowguid'] = df['rowguid'].astype(str)`, but it relies on me knowing which columns have `uniqueidentifier` types. By the time it's a dataframe, everything is an `object` and each query will be different.
- I also know I can convert it to a `char(36)` in the SQL query itself, however, I was hoping to do something more "automatic" so the person writing the query doesn't trip over this problem accidentally all the time / doesn't have to remember to always convert the datatype.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could inspect the table schema and modify the query on the fly to insert the casts but that would be fairly involved.  You could try looking at the first row to see if it is a UUID but that will fail as soon as you hit a query with no rows or all nulls.  Perhaps the simplest solution is to just cast everything with a dtype of `object` to str.  I don't know enough about pymssql/SqlAlchemy to know which other types might manifest as `object`.  If there are other objects then I think you will need to inspect the schema of the table and the cast the matching columns in the dataframe.

Comment: I don't understand why it is so hard, custom serialization will be removed in pyarrow 2.0 and the documentation is very shallow on what to do instead. Just pointing to a IPC functionality that does not deal with this anyhow. There is a description on how to define a UuidType and register it, but it's not saying anything about how to automatically map Uuid to UuidType. The documentation needs to be improved.

Comment: Has anyone had luck extending in a UUIDType? 
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/extending_types.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try DuckDB**

Despite the 'DB' in its name, DuckDB is a Python package that's specifically designed for data analysis tasks and is not a full database replacement. It excels at handling data type conversions without the need for the custom extensions you might encounter when using libraries like PyArrow.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sal
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

# Define your SQL variables
connection_string = "your_connection_string_here"
query = "your_query_here"

# Connect to your SQL database using SQLAlchemy
engine = sal.create_engine(connection_string)
conn = engine.connect()

# Run your query and load the results into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)

# Close the SQL database connection
conn.close()


# My Solution
# With duckdb installed and imported implement the code below
output_file_path = "your_output_file_path_here"

# Connect to DuckDB in-memory
duck_conn = duckdb.connect(':memory:')

# Write the DataFrame (with complex types like UUID) to a 
# snappy-compressed Parquet file with DuckDB
duck_conn.query(f"COPY df TO '{output_file_path}' (FORMAT PARQUET)")

# Close the DuckDB connection
duck_conn.close()
```

**Additional Notes for Consideration:**

It's worth mentioning that there are methods of extending PyArrow with a custom UUIDType, as detailed in the Arrow documentation. However, in my experience, these can lead to further DataType issues, particularly with complex Postgres schemas. This can create a significant maintenance burden. As a result, I find that using DuckDB's native capabilities for these conversion tasks prevents these kinds of complications and recommend it as the more straightforward and reliable solution.

**References:**

- [DuckDB Python API](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/sql_on_pandas)
- [DuckDB Data Types Overview](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/data_types/overview)
- [DuckDB Parquet Integration](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet)
- [Extending PyArrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/extending_types.html)

Comment: appreciate the workaround, but I feel like there should be a way that does not involve installing duckdb.

Comment: changing db is a big project shift. In my mind too much to be a solution.

Comment: I'm still using SQLAlchemy with the SQL database; DuckDB is just a Python package used for its proficiency in handling complex data types during conversion to Parquet. It's not a database replacement, despite the 'DB' in its name. Honestly, it's not even a workaround—it's leveraging DuckDB for its robust Parquet features, making it the better tool for this job.

Comment: From my experience, extending with a custom UUIDType for Arrow can be quite problematic, especially when interfacing with complex Postgres schemas. This approach often leads to more DataType issues down the line. That's why I prefer using DuckDB for conversion tasks. It manages these complex data types more effectively without the need for extensive customizations.